# Add text over canvas chart javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, charts

I have a canvas (chart) that i would like to add text upon ( sum of calculations, or more data by text) is there a way to make the text apear in front of the canvas and not be hidden by it?
(i tried to add text over the canvas, and it was hidden by it.. )
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the Doughnut chart definition, i added the following:

```
  Chart.pluginService.register({
   beforeDraw: function(chart) {
        if(chart.chart.config.type=="doughnut" && chart.canvas.id=="position01"){
        
        chart.clear();
        var width = chart.chart.width,
        height = chart.chart.height,
        ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
        
        // ctx.restore();
        var fontSize = (height / 200).toFixed(2);
        ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        
        var sum = 0;
        input.data.map(p=>sum+=p);
        var ductCostText = "Ducts Cost:" ;//was like that:  textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
        var costText = numberWithCommas(sum.toFixed(2)*200) + "₪";
        textX = 0;// Xcoordinate for the text
        textY = height / 2-120;// the Y coordinant of the cost header

        ctx.fillText(ductCostText, textX, textY);
        
        
        }
 
    }
  });
  // formatting function : format as a price
  function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fairly simple to add text to the canvas. You just need a variable to reference the data that you want to display and then use the canvas api build the text as I've shown below.

elements added to the canvas are, by default, placed above the previously added elements, so as long as your text is created after your chart, it should appear above it.

```js
// make the canvas element and add it to the DOM
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 256;
canvas.height = 256;
canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "white";
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//Create a text string defines the content you want to display
//This could be updated dynamically in your program
let content = "My Data";
//Assign the font to the canvas context.
//The first value is the font size, followed by the names of the
//font families that should be tried:
//1st choice, fall-back font, and system font fall-back
ctx.font = "14px 'Rockwell Extra Bold', 'Futura', sans-serif";
//Set the font color to red
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
//Figure out the width and height of the text
let width = ctx.measureText(content).width,
  height = ctx.measureText("M").width;
//Set the text's x/y registration point to its top left corner
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
//Use `fillText` to Draw the text in the center of the canvas
ctx.fillText(
  content, //The text string
  10, //The x position
  canvas.height / 2 - height / 2 //The y position
);
```

Or, to ensure that the chart image is loaded before we draw anything else on top of it we can do something like this:

```js
// make the canvas element and add it to the DOM
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 360;
canvas.height = 180;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// set the colour of the canvas background
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "#999";
canvas.width = 360; // 360deg
canvas.height = 180;

// declare var to hold our chart/background
let worldImg;

// load our inage or run the code to
// draw the chart
let loadImg = new Promise(() => {
  //Load an image
  worldImg = new Image();
  worldImg.addEventListener("load", loadHandler, false);
  worldImg.src = "https://stuartcodes.000webhostapp.com/pexels-pixabay-41949.png";
  console.log(worldImg);
});

//The loadHandler is called when the image has loaded
function loadHandler() {
  console.log("OK");

  // draw the image that we want as the background
  ctx.drawImage(worldImg, 0, 0);

  // then draw everything else

  /****** Your Data ******\ */
  //Create a text string defines the content you want to display
  //This could be updated dynamically in your program
  let content = "My Data";
  
  //Assign the font to the canvas context.
  //The first value is the font size, followed by the names of the
  //font families that should be tried:
  //1st choice, fall-back font, and system font fall-back
  ctx.font = "14px 'Rockwell Extra Bold', 'Futura', sans-serif";
  
  //Set the font color to red
  ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
  
  //Figure out the width and height of the text
  let width = ctx.measureText(content).width,
    height = ctx.measureText("M").width;
    
  //Set the text's x/y registration point to its top left corner
  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  //Use `fillText` to Draw the text in the center of the canvas
  ctx.fillText(
    content, //The text string
    10, //The x position
    canvas.height / 2 - height / 2 //The y position
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have tried your idea, but when i ran the program - the text is being hidden right after the chart is being loaded. ( you can see the text for a split second, and its being hidden once the chart apears.)  any idea how to make the text apear in front? or maybe as a workaround make the chart background clear?

Comment: sure, you need to load the chart onto the canvas before you define the text object. i.e. put your code to load the chart before my code shown abve

Comment: Apologies, I assumed that the code to generate your chart would run before that which I wrote  above and It's quite funny that I ran into the same problem! What we need to do is to make sure that the chart is loaded BEFORE the code to draw the text, or anything else for that matter, over the chart runs. The most up-to-date way to do this would be with a `promise` structure. I'll find the time to show you how asap, if you still need it. Sorry for the delay getting back.

Comment: Does my second version help you out at all?

Comment: thank you so muchh @Fishbite ,i thought of what you said and i  decided to try and look for a way to create the chart and concider the text WITH it ( and not create them as 2 different creatures) -so i looked up and found the Chart.pluginService.register , that enabless to add text to the chart. thanks again!